# IPhone app is not compatible with IPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have submitted my app to Apple store, It was rejected for some reasons. One of the reasons that my app must be tested and compatible on iPad. Do I need to make my app to be Universal? The 1st version was submitted without any problem and it was not a Universal.

My question is: What do I need to make my app compatible on both iPhone and IPad?

Thanks

Comment: All iPhone apps run as-is on iPads. It should just work unless you are doing something specific to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

No, your app doesn't need to be universal. But it should run on the iPad without modification.

I'm wondering if you're bumping up against the Launch xib bug? If you're using a Launch xib (new in iOS 8) instead of Launch Images, the system will mistakingly treat it like a Universal app.

Otherwise, get an iPad and run your app on it so that you can see what the problem is.

Comment: What about if I use auto layout, Do you think it will fix the problem. What about the 3.5 problem, can i fix it with making my app universal

Comment: Well I don't know what the problem is. You need to figure that out first.

Comment: Auto Layout would perhaps "fix the problem" if the problem is that layout is broken on the iPad. I'm not sure what the 3.5 problem is - are you not having luck running the app on a 3.5" iPhone either? I'd say that yes, you might want to look at Auto Layout then, because it helps make it easier to lay out UI across multiple device sizes.